# Why I get only [] in web page from res.json() in express

Tags: json, mongodb, express, mongoose

So, when I try to display json data in browser I only get [] instead of full data.
I am trying to display data from mongodb using mongoose and express. I have one  collection in database and one document that I am trying to display but I only get []. Why? Here is the code:
app.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Person = require('./Person.model');

const app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = 'mongodb://localhost/project';
mongoose.connect(db);
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => console.log('connection has been made...')).
on('error', (error) => console.log(error));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('It is good to be here');
});

app.get('/persons', function(req, res) {
    Person.find({}).exec(function(error, persons) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(error);
        } else {
            res.json(persons);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('now listening to port 3000'));
```

and Person.model.js :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    favcolor: String,
    osobina: String
});

const Person = mongoose.model('person', PersonSchema);

module.exports = Person;
```

Comment: you do have data in the database, right?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using Promise with Mongoose, you could try to change your code instead of using the callback function like this

```
app.get('/persons', function(req, res) {
  Person.find({}).exec().then(function(persons) {
    res.json(person);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    res.send(error); //Will lead to a 200 with the error message inside
  });
});
```

**Edit**

You should not use `new` when defining a model. I've removed a little redundant code from your model, this is working:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PersonSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    favcolor: String,
    osobina: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('person', PersonSchema);
```

Comment: I still get only [] in the browser and no json data. I tried with other databases and collections and I always get the same result. In mongo shell everything works just fine and there is no errors.

Comment: copied your code and found the error, just remove `new` from the model declaration

Comment: Still doesn't work. I only get []. Considering _new_ it is not an error [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). I restarted mongo, tried all combination of code, checked in mongo shell and still i don't get json data.

Comment: well.. I copied your code. removed `new` and it's working here.. sorry man

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work :( . Even `Person.count()` gives me now 0. Thanks for trying.

Comment: to reiterate. You do have data in the database right? :) add `new Person({name: 'Batman', age: 45}).save();` to a post endpoint and make sure you have data :)

Comment: Yes I have data in database :)